# Prometheus + Django + gunicorn with --preload and multiple processes publishing just one port

Tags: django, prometheus

I'm running **django+prometheus+gunicorn**, exporting `/metrics` using multiple processes per process, as described in [django-prometheus documentation](https://github.com/korfuri/django-prometheus/blob/master/documentation/exports.md). When I run gunicorn with `--reload` and two workers, I can see how ports 8001 and 8002 are opened serving prometheus metrics, one per process. But when I run gunicorn with `--preload`, only port 8001 is opened.

What do I need to do to get one prometheus endpoint per process while using `--preload`?

**django-prometheus settings:**

```
PROMETHEUS_METRICS_EXPORT_PORT_RANGE = range(8001, 8020)
PROMETHEUS_METRICS_EXPORT_ADDRESS = ''
PROMETHEUS_EXPORT_MIGRATIONS = False
```

**Versions:**

```
django==3.1.0
prometheus_client==0.8.0
django-prometheus==2.1.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

Comment: You will have to configure the Prometheus client to run in multiprocess mode

Comment: @trallnag  django-prometheus client handles multiprocess natively. In fact, it works with `gunicorn --reload`. It's only with `gunicorn --preload` when it fails.